# How to remove 0's from a string

Tags: php

I'm looking at the function `trim` but that unfortunately does not remove "0"s how do I add that to it? Should I use `str_replace`?

EDIT:
The string I wanted to modify was a message number which looks like this: 00023460

The function `ltrim("00023460", "0")` does just what I need :) obviously I would not want to use the regular `trim`because it would also remove the ending 0 but since I forgot to add that the answer I got is great :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ php -r 'echo trim("0string0", "0") . "\n";'
string
```

For the zero padded number in the example:

```
$ php -r 'echo ltrim("00023460", "0") . "\n";'
23460
```

Answer (score 2):

The trim function only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string, so you probably need to use str_replace.

If you only need to remove 0s from the beginning and end of the string, you can use the following:

```
$str = '0000hello00';

$clean_string = trim($str, '0'); // 'hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should have been here from the start.

> EDIT: The string I wanted to modify
>   was a message number which looks like
>   this: 00023460

The best solution is probably this for any integer lower then PHP_INT_MAX

$number = (int) '00023460';

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

```
print str_replace( '0', '', "This0string0needs0spaces");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does (see [second parameter `$charlist`](http://docs.php.net/trim)):

```
trim('000foo0bar000', '0')  // 'foo0bar'
```