# Turn a number of int to the correct sum

Tags: php

```
$sum = 000000000117800;

$sum = number_format($sum, 2, ".", ".");
```

I am looking for the output 1 178.

The sum is always a length of 15. Like assigned above. The sum could also be:

```
000000001117800;
```

Then it would be

```
11 178
```

and so on.

The last two defines the decimals: So for example

000000000117805;

would be

1 178,05

My code above gives me: 79.00 though...

I am wondering if I could solve this perhaps with ltrim, but perhaps there is another more better way ?

Comment: the trim function will help you remove the zeroes. You can use this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707356/how-to-remove-0s-from-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, you simply have to use a **string**

```
$sum = "000000000117800";
echo number_format($sum, 2, ".", ".");
```

prints ( http://ideone.com/534ATu )

```
117.800.00
```

Although, you have to divide by `100` to get the fractional part right

```
$sum = "000000000117800";
echo number_format($sum / 100, 2, ".", ".");
```

which prints ( http://ideone.com/A5LFpS )

```
1.178.00
```

the problem is when you assign

```
$sum = 000000000117800;
```

it is already being converted to `79` (as an octal value of `$sum`) and you cannot do anything about it.

so why do strings work? Because `number_format` expetcs `float` as a first argument, so PHP performs conversion from `string` to `float`, which ignores leading `0`'s. As a result we have `117800` which we have to further divide by `100` to get decimals right, then we can use `number_format` for nice display, or simply do (http://ideone.com/IeBCmF)

```
$sum = "000000000117800";
echo $sum / 100;
```

and get

```
1178
```

and for

```
$sum = "000000000117805";
echo $sum / 100;
```

we get

```
1178.05
```

as requested

One final remark about `number_format` - to get desired formatting you should use

```
number_format( $value, 2, ',', ' ')
```

so (http://ideone.com/yDQXde)

```
$sum = "000000000117805";
echo number_format( $sum / 100, 2, ',', ' ');
```

prints

```
1 178,05
```

Comment: No it actually prints 117 805.00

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove the leading 0's before hand. I went to 
 http://writecodeonline.com/php/ 
 and ran the code

```
$sum = 000000000117800;
$sum = number_format($sum, 2, ",", ".");<br>
echo $sum;
```

Then ran the code

```
$sum = 117800;
$sum = number_format($sum, 2, ",", ".");
echo $sum;
```

and it worked, it;s like the leading 0's are causing the numbers to be interpreted as another format (OCTAL as a commenter said) and not decimal.EDIT:

As a solution try ltrim before running the number_format to remove leading0's
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php 
string ltrim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )
Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.

Comment: A number with leading zeroes is interpreted as octal. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: it is not being interpreted as string - if it were, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you number is treated like octal because of leading zero.

`0117` in octal system is exactly `79` in decimal system.

Your initial value `000000000117800` is reduced to `0117` because `8` is not octal digit, so PHP cuts the last digits of your number.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is `79` for two reasons:

1. Numbers starting with a leading zero are octal, octal `0117` is `7*1 + 1*8 + 1*64 == 79`
2. PHP is broken, and will [blindly ignore invalid characters at the end](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#example-69)

Why does your number contain those leading zeros? A number has no concept of "length" - that's a property of it's string representation.